# Rate of change calculus question

Tags: calculus

Mohamed's motorcycle path over $t$ seconds is given by $M(t)=t^3 - 2t^2 +3t$. The side car detaches after 1 second (its path will be along the tangent line). Will Mohamed and the side car meet up again? When?

I know it is a rate of change question but I am confused as to where to start. Can someone please guide me through the question?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $M(t) = t^3 - 2t^2 + 3t$?

Comment: yes u are right

Comment: The function for the tangent line is $y(t)=m\cdot t+b$. Does the hint help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is understanding the problem is to try to figure out what it means for the sidecar to continue on tangentially, and what to do with that information.  Since the motorcycle and the sidecar part at $t=1$, we get $M(1) = 1 - 2 + 3 = 2.$  That is, they part ways at the point $(1, 2).$

Because the sidecar continues on tangentially, we need to find the line tangent to the funtion $M(t)$ at the point $(1, 2).$  This should be screaming at you now to find the derivative of $M(t)$ at $t = 1.$  Let's do that.  We get $M'(t) = 3t^2 - 4t^ + 3$ so that $M'(1) = 3 - 4 + 3 = 2.$  What does this value represent?  Well, the sidecar is going in a straight line, and the slope of this line is $2.$ We also know that the line passes through $(1,2).$  Thus the equation of the line would be given by $y - 2 = 2 (t - 1)$ giving $y = 2t.$

From here we set $y = M(t)$ to find where they intersect.  We get $2t = t^3 - 2t^2 + 3t,$ so that $0 = t^3 - 2t^2 + t = t(t - 1)^2.$  Therefore they intersect at $t = 0$ and $t = 1$.  Since they never intersect again after $t = 1$ (when the motorcycle and sidecar come apart), they will never meet again.